# WINCE 7: SDCard is not mounting with EMAC driver

Tags: windows-ce, sd-card, ethernet

We are working with WINCE 7 sdmmc driver,which is Working properly without EMAC driver.

Once EMAC driver is enable in Catalog Item, sdcard  is mounting only fewer times. Most of the times SD folder is not shown in the MyDevice (Where as in Storage Manager control Panel applet SD is listed)

Here i added SDMMC part of Platform.reg file :

```
IF BSP_SDMMC
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Drivers\BuiltIn\SDMMC1]
    "Order"=dword:26
    "Dll"="sdmmc.dll"
    "Prefix"="MMC"
    "Index"=dword:1
    ;"DisableDMA"=dword:1                                      ; Use this reg setting to disable both internal and external DMA
    "MaximumClockFrequency"=dword:2FAF080           ; 50 MHz max clock speed
    ;"WakeupSource"=dword:1                                  ; this will enable system wakeup when card is inserted or removed during suspend state


ENDIF ;BSP_SDMMC
```

Emac.reg file:

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Comm\EMAC1]
   "DisplayName"="EMAC Ethernet Driver"
   "Group"="NDIS"
   "ImagePath"="EMAC.dll"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Comm\EMAC1\Parms]
   "BusNumber"=dword:0
   "BusType"=dword:0
   "IRQ"=dword:98
   "ioBase"=dword:31
   "ioLen"=dword:10
   "memBase"=dword:D03CD610
   "memLen"=dword:1000
   "Order"=dword:30
   ; DuplexMode: 0:AutoDetect; 1:HalfDuplex; 2:FullDuplex.
   "DuplexMode"=dword:0
   ; The Ethernet Physical Address. For example,
   ; Ethernet Address 00:24:20:10:bf:03 is MACAddress1=0024,
   ; MACAddress2=2010,and MACAddress3=bf03.
   "MACAddress1"=dword:0001
   "MACAddress2"=dword:0203
   "MACAddress3"=dword:0405
   "*IfType"=dword:6               ; IF_TYPE_IEEE802_3
   "*MediaType"=dword:0            ; NdisMediumNative802_3
   "*PhysicalMediaType"=dword:D   ; NdisPhysicalMedium802_3
```

Please help me out from this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is the order of `SDMMC` and what is the order of `EMAC` driver?

Which is loading first?

Change these orders and try.

Answer (score 1):

Issue got solved after I change the order of EMAC from 5 to 30 (larger that SDMMC order).